# Should I need to make the iTunes Artwork image round cornered?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Do I need to make my iTunes artwork have rounded corners when submitting an app to the App Store?

Comment: NO,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple will add round corners to your icons by itself.

Comment: I know that Apple adds round corners for inside app icons if I set the flag in info.plist, but not sure about iTunes Artwork.. So is your answer applicable for AppStore Itnues artwork too ?

Comment: There is no any flag in `info.plist` that can handle adding of rounded corners to your app icon. Apple adds this corners to all icons including iTunes Artwork

Comment: I'm too agree with Nekto, Apple adds round corners for iTune's artwork.

Comment: right, it's only for glossy effects. 
Thanks Nekto

Comment: If I answered on your question, don't forget to accept it. Ty

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make an icon round-cornered for submission to Apple.  They add the corners, and optionally the highlight.  However if you want to display an icon similar to the way it is displayed by Apple, but on your own website, you will need to make matching round-cornered artwork for your own use.

Comment: I don't know why your and my answer was -1 by someone. But I have upvoted as your answer is also right.